# Please help explain this SQL statement

Tags: sql

The table `Arc(x,y)` currently has the
following tuples (note there are
duplicates):

```
(1,2),
(1,2),
(2,3),
(3,4),
(3,4),
(4,1),
(4,1),
(4,1),
(4,2)
```

Compute the result of the query:

```
SELECT a1.x, a2.y, COUNT(*)
FROM Arc a1, Arc a2
WHERE a1.y = a2.x
GROUP BY a1.x, a2.y;
```

What are `a1` and `a2` referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a1 and a2 are just aliases for the Arc table which is being joined to itself.  You could also say,

```
Arc As a1, Arc As a2
```

Is that what you're asking?

Comment: it works because it's the same as saying Arc = "a1" and Arc = "a2"

Answer (score 4):

It's called a `self join`.

You may join a table with itself, as in your task, it will result in:

```
(1, 2) (2, 3)  // note the join condition, y from the right is equal to x from the left
(1, 2) (2, 3)
(2, 3) (3, 4)
(2, 3) (3, 4)
...
```

etc.

This will of course shrink after `GROUP`'ing.

`a1` and `a2` refer to the instances of the table. From which part of the result you want the `x`? Use `a1.x` for the left part, `a2.x` for the right part.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the query is:

```
create temp table arc(x int, y int);
insert into arc values(1,2);
insert into arc values(1,2);
insert into arc values(2,3);
insert into arc values(3,4);
insert into arc values(3,4);
insert into arc values(4,1);
insert into arc values(4,1);
insert into arc values(4,1);
insert into arc values(4,2);

SELECT a1.x, a2.y, COUNT(*)
FROM Arc a1, Arc a2
WHERE a1.y = a2.x
GROUP BY a1.x, a2.y;

      4           3                1
      4           2                6
      2           4                2
      1           3                2
      3           1                6
      3           2                2
```

This is not necessarily the answer to the question, though.  As already noted, 'a1' and 'a2' are table aliases, alternative names for the Arc table so that it can be joined to itself.